# AsyncGenerator javascript function giving "Syntax error on token "return", Identifier expected" in eclipse mars

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jspdf

I getting this error "Syntax error on token "return", invalid Type" on this little bit of code of java script and I'm having trouble figuring out.

Thanks.

I am getting error on AsyncGenerator in Jspdf File.

```
      AT 1. gen.return
         2. AsyncGenerator.prototype.throw
         3. AsyncGenerator.prototype.next
```

I have done bold all errors.

```js
var asyncGenerator = function () {
  function AwaitValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  function AsyncGenerator(gen) {
    var front, back;

   
    if (typeof gen.return == "function") {
      this.return= undefined;
      
    }
  }

  if (typeof Symbol === "function" && Symbol.asyncIterator) {
    AsyncGenerator.prototype[Symbol.asyncIterator] = function () {
      return this;
    };
  }

  AsyncGenerator.prototype.next = function (arg) {
    return this._invoke("next", arg);
  };

  AsyncGenerator.prototype.throw = function (arg) {
    return this._invoke("throw", arg);
  };

  AsyncGenerator.prototype.return = function (arg) {
    return this._invoke("return", arg);
  };

  return {
    wrap: function (fn) {
      return function () {
        return new AsyncGenerator(fn.apply(this, arguments));
      };
    },
    await: function (value) {
      return new AwaitValue(value);
    }
  };
}();
```

**strong text**

Comment: Where is the Java? I only see JavaScript here.

Comment: wtf is this supposed to be `***return !***`

Comment: @Deryck I think OP was trying to bold the lines that the IDE says have errors, but because OP also put the code in code blocks (which is good), it treats `**` as code and not a style. Maybe code comments would work better?

Comment: was trying to bold errros in post ....@Deryck

Comment: 1. use code comments next time like @Rainbolt mentioned and 2. you should try not to use javascript keywords for everything.  Not saying they are causing your issue here it's just good to eliminate as a possibility

Comment: What `function AsyncGenerator(gen) {
    var front, back;

   
    if (typeof gen.return == "function") {
      this.return= undefined;
      
    }
  }` is suppose to do ?